# StartActivity in Broadcastreceiver opens up the app every time it is called

Tags: android, xamarin.android, background-process

I have a `BroadcastReceiver`, and on its `OnReceive` I am supposed to call a method which is defined in the `MainActivity`. wherever I searched I found that I will have to write the following code.

```
Bundle bundle = intent.Extras;
Intent callingIntent = new Intent(context, typeof(MainActivity));
callingIntent.PutExtra("isSynched", true);
callingIntent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
callingIntent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.SingleTop);
context.StartActivity(callingIntent);
```

Now this calls my method, but the app keeps opening up. I don't want that to happen. I want the method to be called when the app is in background and want the app to be in background. What should I do? I am using xamarin to write the code.
I have created a service that gets the data but after I receive data I have to call a method in MainActivity to update the calendar. I am currently doing it in OnReceive like this, public override void

```
OnReceive(Context context, Android.Content.Intent intent)
{
    if (context.GetType().Equals(typeof(MainActivity)))
    {
        ((MainActivity)context).SyncCalendar();
    }
}
```

this context is coming as restrictedaccess. So not able to call SyncCalendar Method

Comment: if you need to do things in your app in the background, without an activity visible, use a service.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether you need or not execute that code all the time your app lives, I'd recommend:

- **AsyncThread**: This is somelike an improved version of a `Thread` as it already implements some of the mechanisms you would need to set manually with a `Thread`, but it's not recommended to execute all your app life, just for ending processes. You may find more info [there](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)
- **Service**: Otherwise, if your function is intended to run all your app's life long, Service is the correct choice. It's a bit harder to understand than the AsyncThread, as it's a class that it's executed until you stop it paralelly to your main UI, but it's not a thread. You may find [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) useful and also [this](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Android_Remote_Bound_Services_%E2%80%93_A_Worked_Example).

Comment: I have created a service that gets the data but after I recieve data i have to call a method in MainActivity to update the calendar. I am currently doing it in OnRecieve like this, public override void
`OnReceive(Context context, Android.Content.Intent intent)
        {
            if (context.GetType().Equals(typeof(MainActivity)))
            {
                ((MainActivity)context).SyncCalendar();
            }}`
this context is coming as restrictedaccess. So not able to call SyncCalendar Method

Comment: Simply add another BroadcastReceiver in your MainActivity and do the same process. That's the good thing about them, you can place them where you need the times you need.

Comment: I did not understand. Can you please add a sample code? I am stuck on this for hours now

Comment: Ok, now I think I understood what you want to achieve. Try this: ((Activity) context).SyncCalendar(); and see if that works.

Comment: SyncCalendar() is a method defined in my Activity called MainActivity. but when the onrecieve is called, it gives exception, that it cannot typecast. Actually the context comes as restrictedaccess and i am not able to typecast it to MainActivity so not able to access SyncCalendar()

Comment: So the BroadcastReceiver is **outside** your MainActivity, right? In that case, define another BroadcastReceiver **inside** your MainActivity, and whenever you get a message, simply call SyncCalendar(), you will be able because it will be in the context of your Activity.

Comment: I made it work.. but i removed the UnregisterBroadcast from the OnPause and OnStart. So it is working.. Is a good practice?

Comment: It is a good practice as far as you don't want your broadcast to be stopped on those events. There are many examples where it is valid, for example, if you have a TCP socket which is continuously receiving/sending data (even when the app is paused). If it helped you, mark this answer so other users may know it's helpful. Thanks!